# Auto submit form when value from input text is selected (autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I would like to auto submit a form when a value from the autocomplete input text is selected.

I'm actually trying something like this but it auto submit each time the text is filled.

```
$('input.text').on('keyup', function() { 
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code from http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select :

```
$("#searchField").autocomplete({
     source: "values.json",
     minLength: 2,
     select: function(event, ui) { 
     $("#searchField").val(ui.item.value);
     $("#form").submit(); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I imagine that the code is good and it probably didn't work on my side because I use the WordPress Autocomplete plugin. I'll look to how override it.

Comment: I made changes in the WP plugin and it works well now, thanks again @Pawan.